# Proof of the CDF of a discrete random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let X be a discrete random variable with finite value range, i.e. it applies $X(\Omega) = \{x_1,...,x_n\} \text{ for }n\in\mathbb N$, where $x_1\lt\cdots\lt x_n.$

a) From the definition $$F(x):=\mathbb P(X\le x) \text{ for } x\in\mathbb R$$ prove that for all $x\in\,(x_i,x_{i+1})$ holds $$F(x)=F(x_i)$$

b) Prove that $$F(x)=\sum_{x_i\le x}\mathbb P(X=x_i)$$

I've just started my bachelor degree (Statistics) this spring, so it should be possible to prove both of these using just properties of the CDF and Kolmogorov axioms. However, due to my lack of knowledge, I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Comment: If $x_i<x<x_{i+1}$ then $\mathbb P(X \le x)=\mathbb P(X \le x_i)+ \mathbb P(x_i \lt X \le x)$, but $\mathbb P(x_i \lt X \le x)\le \mathbb P(x_i \lt X \lt x_{i+1})=0$ since these are impossible events, meaning $F(x)=\mathbb P(X \le x)=\mathbb P(X \le x_i)+0=F(x_i)$

Comment: @Henry Thank you so much! It totally makes sense now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think visually and it helps you to understand the result.

Suppose that $p_1 = P(X = x_1), p_2 = P(X = x_2), \ldots, p_n = P(X = x_n)$, as there are only a finite number of mass points $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$.

Given also that the mass points are ordered, i.e.

$x_1 < x_2 < \cdots < x_n$.

For all values of $x < x_1$, it follows that

$
F(x) = P(X \leq x) = 0
$

Now, for values of $x \in [x_1, x_2)$, we see that

$
F(x) = P(X \leq x) = P(X = x_1) = p_1
$

Next, for values of $x \in [x_2, x_3)$, we see that

$
F(x) = P(X \leq x) = P(X = x_1) + P(X = x_2) = p_1 + p_2
$

In general, for $x \in [x_k, x_{k + 1})$, where $k \leq n - 1$, we have

$
F(x) = P(X \leq x) = P(X = x_1) + \cdots + P(X = x_k) = p_1 + p_2 + \cdots + p_k
$

Finally, for $x \geq x_n$, we have
$
F(x) = P(X \leq x) = P(X = x_1) + \cdots + P(X = x_k) = p_1 + p_2 + \cdots + p_n = 1
$

(Since the total probability of a discrete probability mass function = 1).

If you plot $F(x)$ graphically, you will see that $F$ is a piecewise constant function, which is monotone non-decreasing..

These calculations also establish the following:

$
\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow -\infty} F(x) = 0
$

and

$
\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow  \infty} F(x) = 1
$

Comment: Thank you so much, Dr. Sundar! It took a couple of times re-reading your answer, but I've finally managed to understand it! :)

Comment: I have written a book on Probability, Random Variables and Random Processes, which has been adopted as a text-book in many Indian Universities.. With best wishes, Sundar